# escaping sh/bash function arguments

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to submit multiple commands with arguments to shell functions, and thus quote my commands like his:

```
$ CMD=''\''CMD'\'' '\''ARG1 ARG2 ARG3'\'''
$ echo $CMD
'CMD' 'ARG1 ARG2 ARG3' 'ARG4'
```

Now when I try to us them in a function like this:

```
$ function execute { echo "$1"; echo "$2"; echo "$3"; }
```

I get the result:

```
$ execute $CMD
'CMD'
'ARG1
ARG2
```

How can I get to this result:

```
$ execute $CMD
CMD
ARG1 AGR2 ARG3
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: I use an unquoting function like:

```
function unquote { echo "$1" | xargs echo; }
```

EDIT:

to make my intentions more clear: I want to gradually build up a command that needs arguments with spaces passed to subfunctions:

```
$ CMD='HOST '\''HOSTNAME'\'' '\''sh SCRIPTNAME'\'' '\''MOVE '\''\'\'''\''/path/to/DIR1'\''\'\'''\'' '\''\'\'''\''/path/to/DIR2'\''\'\'''\'''\'''
$ function execute { echo "$1 : $2 : $3 : $4"; }
$ execute $CMD
HOST : 'HOSTNAME' : 'sh : SCRIPTNAME'
```

The third arguments breaks unexpected at a space, the quoting is ignored. ??

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array and @ in double quotes:

```
function execute () {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$3"
}

CMD=('CMD' 'ARG1 ARG2 ARG3' 'ARG4')
execute "${CMD[@]}"
```

Comment: choroba, that's actually very nice, but I don't know how to implement that in my case. I am gradually building up my command and append and prepend options to it. And I am also nesting them,, that's why I need to use that double quoting (it's not escaping as I wrote). Any hints on why that quoting fails and how to circumvent it?

Comment: The quoting fails because quoting simply does not nest. That's why arrays were introduced to `bash` and nearly every other shell that extends the POSIX specification.

Comment: @jlue the only proper way to achieve what you want is to use arrays as shown in this post. Please read more about arrays (how to append and prepend elements, how to concatenate two arrays). That's the only simple and safe way to go!

Answer (score 2):

```
function execute { 
  while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
      cmd=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <<< $1)
      arg=$(sed 's/[^ ]* //' <<< $1)
      echo "$cmd receives $arg"
      shift
  done
}

CMD1="CMD1 ARG11 ARG12 ARG13"
CMD2="CMD2 ARG21 ARG22 ARG23"
execute "$CMD1" "$CMD2"
```

Gives:

```
CMD1 receives ARG11 ARG12 ARG13
CMD2 receives ARG21 ARG22 ARG23
```

Comment: perreal, that's also very nice but my problem is, that the quoting fails (yes, it's not escaping) in my example. Any clues on how to get that right? I am also actually nesting the commands.